# multiples of k below n (recursively)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, counting

I don't understand how to make the program as described.

I can do it in a non-generalized form, where I know what k is beforehand, but I don't know how to generalize it.

So if i know k is 7, then i can do it. But if i have to generalize it it doesn't work that way. What I need is a generalized version of what I have below

```
def multiples(k, n):
"""prints multiples of 7 below 500
"""

if k<=n:
    print(k)
    k+=7
    multiples(k, n)
multiples(7, 500)
```

Comment: You need two different variables. One for the value of `k`, which in your example is 7, but which never changes; and another variable, not named `k`, for the multiples. In your code you named the multiples `k` as well, which is the source of the confusion.

Comment: Also note that `0` is a multiple of 7, too.

Comment: Also, you could just do `for m in range(0, n, k): print(m)`. There is no need for recursion here, and in python it is best to avoid recursion for these kinds of tasks. In some other languages, recursion is great. But in python it is really bad to use recursion for this. If your goal is to study recursion, don't use python.

Comment: @Stef it's seems pretty likely this is homework and so people don't get a choice on the language and how they're required to implement a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `start` parameter to your function, which defaults to `0`:

```py
def multiples(k, n, start=0):
    if (start <= n):
        print(start)
        start += k
        multiples(k, n, start)

multiples(7, 500)
```

Output:

```
0
7
14
...
497
```

Comment: @mozway thanks. Curious as to what you'd do differently?

Comment: not nicer than yours: `print(step*k) ; if k<=n:  multiples(k, n-k, step=step+1)`

Comment: Gotcha. I was trying to make mine look more like the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of the original value of `k`, which you wrote as `7` in your attempt.

I'd add a helper function, and do my recursion with that:

```py
def multiples(k0, n):
    def _multiples(k):
        if k > n: return []
        return [k] + _multiples(k + k0)

    return _multiples(0)

print(multiples(7, 500))  # [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, ..., 497]
```